# Collection create function firing add event too quickly

Tags: backbone.js

(Using Backbone 0.9.10)

I have a list view of sorts where the user can click a button to show a modal view. The list view has a counter that shows the amount of items contained in the list. Clicking a button in the modal view executes `create` on a collection that is passed into both views. This fires the `add` event in the list view, which in turn runs this function:

```
renderCount: function () {
    // Container for model count
    var $num = this.$el.find('.num');

    if ($num.length > 0) {
        // 'count' is a value returned from a service that
        // always contains the total amount of models in the
        // collection. This is necessary as I use a form of
        // pagination. It's essentially the same as
        // this.collection.length had it returned all models
        // at once.
        $num.html(this.collection.count);
    }
}
```

However, `add` seems to be fired immediately (as it should be, according to the docs), before the collection has a chance to update the model count. I looked into `sync` but it didn't seem to do much of anything.

How can I make sure the collection is updated *before* calling `renderCount`?

Here's the list view `initialize` function, for reference:

```
initialize: function (options) {
    this.collection = options.collection;
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add remove reset', this.renderCount);

    this.render();
}
```

**EDIT:**
Turns out I was forgetting to refetch the collection on `success` in the modal view.

Comment: How do you update the `count`attribute? With an AJAX request?

Comment: @nikoshr Thank you. This hinted to what I was forgetting, namely a fetch to update the collection on create success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was forgetting to refetch the collection on `success` in the modal view.

Answer (score 0):

```
$num.html(this.collection.count);
```

shoule be:

```
$num.html(this.collection.size());
```

Backbone.Collection uses methods imported from underscore, here is list: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods

Comment: `count` is a custom variable in the collection. Its purpose is not the same in this context.